# TS: `unions can't be used in index signatures, use a mapped object type instead` Then mapped object is not passed as string/number

Tags: typescript, index-signature

After getting the error `unions can't be used in index signatures, use a mapped object type instead` I am now attempting to convert a string literal union (key names of an interface) to a mapped object, as explained here. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24220#issuecomment-390063153

But it still isn't working:

```
const returnObject: { 
   [index : mappedObjectOfConfigDataKeys] : Partial<ConfigData>
 } = {...accumulator};

// error TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

// 51 [index : // mappedObjectOfConfigDataKeys] : // Partial<ConfigData>
//     ~~~~~


 if (currentStepInstance.hasSaveableData && currentStepInstance.configDataKey) {
    returnObject[currentStepInstance.configDataKey] = validatedUserInput;
 } 
// error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
//  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

// 55  returnObject[currentStepInstance.configDataKey] = validatedUserInput;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

To prove the prior issue:

```
const returnObject: { 
   [index : stringLiteralUnion] : Partial<ConfigData>
 } = {...accumulator};

// (parameter) index: stringLiteralUnion
// An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)
```

Anyone know how to fix this? These last two attempts have me in circles. The compiler seems to  want the mapped object to pass a constrained set of strings; I don't know how to give it that in an acceptable way.

```
export default interface ConfigData {
   languageCode : string
   , numberOfRepeats : number
   , projectId : string
}

/**** Index Signature handling for the above interface ****/
export type stringLiteralUnion = "languageCode" | "numberOfRepeats" | "projectId";

export type mappedObjectOfConfigDataKeys = {[key in stringLiteralUnion]: string}; 
// also tried typing it as `any` as shown in the linked post
// same error occured
```

**Typescript Playground**

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=29&ssc=16&pln=29&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28CWA7GYKNAY2DgGEI9kcBzAEVRlTgG8AoObzVPO9KjrAqSOAC44AZxhR8dLtwA0cPOgC2AIyIB5ZACVgYYMykTVG7VEVwVYKBABWwEjACSCczLn8OAXw4OAHoAKjCQuDc8JBA4AGV6PGZ0KHIACz4ETHk4ZGg4GDTyVE0IADdyfEJiVDI4cJCgjlBIWAKAT2NpWXkAGRxq1EwAVTwcajgAXjgAIl5%20QWFRYBm4AB9ZtS1dAyMTGClVjZn7Jxd3BBmAbkCW6HgYTvJ1VDBjBB1NZ1c9Khp6JgsADSwHaZmmbDgAG0ANaguD4bo%20Oj9QYjMbUAC6km8OT8N2CQTgAHUcAAvVBQBBxQhgMxRaqkYCBKpEJkk8mU6m0sycbhwVKoBDUTDtOAZKRxVAVEqYYCA1CSUoQOV8GwqQXCvCi1TAYAIKQAMRwcoAakMcAhmOM8EqICqTHh1QKTFqdfgyhaEFEwOgYABZYBSKRCYAAfhxPX46zg6GiKHw%20udmpFYpI1FojGYqBB7QjSJyGzjSFoeCTzpavHwAAoAJSSMoQS3O07qMAwOuR5HOz3ZK2EH1%206voKREQcwfO46NF%20Ol-X1uDK1VO-kqXuW5jAY1ysPV2hygAKzDSk6jdBjxYTZYQC6XjpjjebAUCQSJFF4wbgAHcBmk4ERkTgdRgEKCAEECEgPzMOIQPQMBSQpKl2BsV84AAWgwzCsOwuADwcYxYBwIMbHsHBPUIbojCkSQAEEoCgVB2gAHgQrkaSogA%20G5%20RsdM8G8dBXGgashkwdi6Vo%20jGJYzkqXEqQONrZD%20X5QocCkAA6GQqKmOBRPk7juGfHj%20VQ7DzKw3D0E0bISDgQNQINLgUIiAAJTI5TgTB7TAHIIGQAoikosAvIgOgcBIGx%20QAUVqP9tJCn9MEwf9wCrPANPiCBgO-E0UvXftKjwX0YBsRoSOs2yETGGAcCGGCYDgztKAzAFs2UlS4FQqA4z05Lgs0lq2xNIMBtywoXUaqAkhs8gYSCMo4DAVAcCgMwqggPS4D4zM4AgL5zkCTrtuoGQTv%20LMWF0tTNISzTUgQQTgGrKLOpEkgSA0LBmGgSQj0IoYmL%20TMFQ4lRPvo4ACHEqIZD4MhJFYuSeQXf7asB4G2pYDiphxvlju4PipAdDTvLoasZlqT71G%20mBoBmFQqa%203g6agWsCQJ7hUPwATXFelSIdSaHaVhlg8DIDTKxWvA6w5znUO8iAQrjWqUtYArqpKhEzFSKbr350yiVAAYTrEdS%20uJ8UPKTTnzrOgrNwQYZRygccuxyaYbo04QYHNPtx2rQWoZgGH%20LFsh2YNwnTpJsnqwAcgdwgnZd8d47XL1Hedsdir9SOo66okbIgEgYTMFWTTgDX90qMw8mLFQJhrqvM9qiY7oLnAAsDlIhZDkWw-h4ANLLfUjRGv2NzbvA4AAMln7be%20D0O4fF4ek63EalPx23F8h4WjFFoeNI37dnsj23jPloldZSGfWHmxbltW3J8ju8a-xwNt7j4XBc4OAuRN4C32mp8b4MBJCGHTFSJicw%20ACFDMsI4mxLA7EMMYUwyCTgOHAR4BmuFKTo0wEDVql1UAcRxhCDS1CmY0xZtAfEgRO7dyDgfMAR814aQlFKGUs0FRzwXqw-uh9B6cJ2ljHMoJt4F35CAvAYDzhQiESvcOw9xFkNzJiXSG8U45xKoZAmfg4BHU5nIyad8FGuAMfyPwKg2B%20CUqgMwmMyFXELnpYMRBgGwWmh0LoEwNIPSenWExAsY5ylJmFBOyAsApX2uAyQ6iFTp3OiDbMtZ%20ZmKSdmAxV9jEoSJBZIpcBXLAEwARICIE0hgSkKE0I9lpa5DjK4G02sCibUVsrAglc%20Caz9G0pAwBgKeAKvzSe-Z8jmz4iwRMnhESFHIPE84CIDhlOQIzD6QZ9RVzqogQSMI-HyDKk0fkpxCCuG2T7cZAd1HiURrJbkVEFxTnPDvfkX40gjTgNWWQ6BgDSNtkAgUqAvxuwLNGaYtzaQaVbO2WWoTjqoRIEUUur8oB6RnsbeAvY-kFy9liigKKYTVgYqC-%20%20dAWnT-iVNwUhxl2gdL0yFpDxIn1bsAAOpLxwUs5l3b5%20AaV0q9AC3e5jfFcv-tYzqRiymjg6rvImscolQqMBpD0XpxyBmDKGDJl9%20Z5NUmkBwX5dQmuivRYSMw4jVKwJ4bQsY8CCmRbKFYF8jJMNOXIci5ACVEuHKnf%207t%20AirCWHVQ0AXjZDJPqbOrt-66RHHov0GkejqDrCmiAvQIBfiIBQJx58pX-i2KlAYyxeQlvgNMGYWL8EAEd0AmyrfWgYqwDXcD5dWPAEaLTRt0XGrWkxB0VrLZLEAJs1hrBkV2qAkbyQxoDQOodBKwJBg0s20qu8Q0E1OGQYMo6BjwuOgEd1-gOBAA)

**Update 1**

Attempted:

```
const returnObject: Record<keyof ConfigData, Partial<ConfigData>> = {...accumulator};
```

Error message:

```
const returnObject: Record<"languageCode" | "numberOfRepeats" | "projectId", Partial<ConfigData>>

Type '{ languageCode?: string | undefined; numberOfRepeats?: number | undefined; projectId?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"languageCode" | "numberOfRepeats" | "projectId", Partial<ConfigData>>'.

  Types of property 'languageCode' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ConfigData>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ConfigData>'.ts(2322)
```

**Update 2**

Attempted:

```
const returnObject: Record<"languageCode" | "numberOfRepeats" | "projectId", Partial<ConfigData>> = {...accumulator};
```

Error:

```
const returnObject: Record<"languageCode" | "numberOfRepeats" | "projectId", Partial<ConfigData>>

Type '{ languageCode?: string | undefined; numberOfRepeats?: number | undefined; projectId?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"languageCode" | "numberOfRepeats" | "projectId", Partial<ConfigData>>'.

  Types of property 'languageCode' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ConfigData>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ConfigData>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you want an object with the same keys as `ConfigData`, and what is supposed to be the values? could you provide a link to typescript playground or something?

Comment: @DPro The goal is to clear the two errors on both of the statements in the 1st code block. I think it will involve typing `returnObject`'s index signature string values correctly (it may be something else though). I've posted a link to a TS playground above

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to achieve:

```
const returnObject: Record<keyof ConfigData, Partial<ConfigData>> = {...accumulator};
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted the new error as an update to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing the index signature to a mapped object, I needed to convert the value to a mapped type.

This line:

```
const returnObject: { 
   [index : mappedObjectOfConfigDataKeys] : Partial<ConfigData>
 } = {...accumulator};
```

becomes this:

```
const returnObject: Partial<ConfigData> = accumulator;
```